# <urlopen error [SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1007)>

Tags: python-3.x, undetected-chromedriver

When I am tried to use undetected_chromedriver to replace the default driver like this in macOS 13.4:

```
# coding=utf-8
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = uc.Chrome(headless=False, use_subprocess=False)
    driver.get('https://nowsecure.nl')
    driver.save_screenshot('nowsecure.png')
```

this code shows error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 1348, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1283, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1329, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1278, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1038, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 976, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1455, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 513, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1104, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1375, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLEOFError: [SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1007)
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 1351, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1007)>
python-BaseException
```

why did this happen? is it possible to avoid this issue?